# Is there any material covering the interim between seasons 2 & 3 in Falling Skies?

Tags: falling-skies

So, season 2 ends on a *huge* cliffhanger. Then, there's 7 months of in-universe time between seasons 2 & 3. After this, season 3 picks up almost as if the audience has missed nothing. Major details regarding developments during the intervening months are casually brought forth as the plot deems them necessary, but I'm still left wondering what *exactly* happened immediately after the last episode of season 2?

Is there any additional material (e.g.: webisodes, comics, etc.) that shows us events that occurred in the time between seasons 2 & 3, or are we just left to wonder?

Comment: We are just left to wonder. JJ Abrams used exactly the same device of letting a large amount of time lapse offscreen in another of his series, _Fringe_.

Comment: @RossPresser: Your statement could be read as if Falling Skies were a series by JJ Abrams ("another of his series"), but I don't see any mention of him in the [WP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_Skies).

Comment: Oops. I made a bad assumption. I did think JJ was involved in Falling Skies.

Comment: @RossPresser The statement is still relevant though, as it makes a good comparison. The only minor point would be that "another" should be "one", but it's too late for that edit now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there hasn't been anything given to us yet that tells us exactly what happened in that missing time. As you said they are only giving us details as they are relevant to the story line.

This is what Noah Wyle says about it:

> "We employ a bit of a time jump," Wyle explained. "The first episode starts seven months after the finale, so a lot has happened in the interim. This new race of beings called the Volm have landed, proven themselves to be trustworthy, and pitched an alliance with the humans to fight their common enemy, the Espheni, the Overloads of Skitters, we met last year."

Lots of shows do this sort of thing to encourage the intrigue and get people wanting to find out more. As Ross said JJ Abrams seems to be fond of doing this, having used it as a major plot point in shows like Fringe (where we jump 20+ years into the future and we watch as they rediscover and explain what happened) and Alias (where Sydney wakes up with no memory of the previous two years and we watch as she rediscovers what happened).

Falling Skies is a little different in the sense that they all remember what happened and we are the only ones that don't know. In addition to the bits and pieces of info they give us throughout the season they have still left it open to dedicate entire episodes to this missing time.

Answer (score 0):

its also very possible that they wrote up until a certain point 2 leaving room for adaption depending on how the series was received since season 1 received an ok response. After they learned season 2 was being received better they began writing more content and by the time season 2 concluded needed additional time ti complete the script. I always try and think of the more real world implications rather than fan/audience orientated reason. complete speculation of course

Comment: You might want to make it a comment if you're not sure, at least when you have sufficient rep.  Also, please try to work on your mechanics.

Comment: Welcome to SFF. Please visit our tour page to see the kind answers we are looking for. We tend to avoid pure speculation unless the theory is backed up by some form of canon.